# What are the best practices to implement a notification to a Queue manager?

Tags: assignment-rules, notification

Hello Stackexchangers,

I'm working on project right now where I'm looking to send a notification to a record owner's manager. Since we need to work with Queues (as Owner of records), I'm looking for the best way to implement something like this, since the people associated to the Queue might have different managers (if only there was a way to assign a manager/supervisor directly to a Queue).

I thought of maybe assigning a Role to the Queue, and to contact the Subordinate of the actual Role, but I would probably have to add some Apex code to make it work perfectly.

Is there a clean way to do so with the core Salesforce features?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there isn't straight forward way to do this. I personally would try to create queues based on teams and then the queue email would be the email of the manager (flattened version of roles).